# Fedora 38 does not find install of Fedora 34

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, fedora, grub

I have a SDD with BTRFS. I have a Fedora 34 (old) install in it. I installed Fedora 38 in a new subvolume. I want to boot the old Fedora, but it is not in the boot menu.

This is an EFI system.

When I run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` with the old system root mounted on `/mnt/old_system`, I get this:

```
# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found Fedora 34 (Thirty Four) on /dev/sda3
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

However, it does not add an entry to Fedora 34 (old), just the new one.

How can I make grub2-mkconfig add an entry for the old Fedora install?